# Use SoundPool with URIs?

Tags: java, android, uri, soundpool

Is there any way to load URIs of sound files into a SoundPool? I tried `poolMap.put(id, spool.load(sfxURI.getPath(), 0));` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wont work reliably except you know what length the fiels have on the server. use mediaplayer. soundpool is only made for short sounds. read the SDK page. :)